# Python : Replace None value None with value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to merge 2 dataframes and fill the None value with another column

[image]

This is my input and I want the output to be like this

[image]

here is the code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'employee': ['Bob', 'Jake', 'Lisa', 'Sue'],
                    'group': [ 'HR', 'Engineering',None, None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'employee': [ 'Bob','Jake', 'Lisa', 'Sue'],
                  'group': [None,None,'Accounting','Engineering' ]})
```

i tried this :

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2,on='employee')
```

but dosen't show the output i want it

Comment: Can you include your code in the question?

Comment: Images are not copyable :-( Please show your dataframes as **text**

Comment: i edit it , here is  the code above

Comment: Use `df_new = df1.set_index('employee').combine_first(df2.set_index('employee')).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael thanks you so much that works fine